# "go build" became very slow after installing a new version of Go

Tags: go

After upgrading from Go 1.2.1 to 1.3 (Windows 7 64 bit) "go build" execution time has increased from around 4 to over 45 seconds. There were no other changes except the go version update. Switching off the virus scanner seems to have no effect. Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking, and/or downgraded back to the previous version?

Comment: I tried to downgrade to the previous version before 1.3 (which is 1.2.2), but it's as slow as 1.3. I'll try 1.2.1 next.

Comment: I'm suspecting this might have to do with the self-optimization of software. Perhaps if you use Go 1.3 a bit it will work efficiently again. Thanks for the question, though, I'm also curious if anyone has an answer. :)

Comment: what this got to do with jruby ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You probably have dependencies that are being recompiled each time. Try `go install -a mypackage` to rebuild all dependencies.

Removing `$GOPATH/pkg` also helps to ensure you don't have old object files around.

Building with the `-x` flag will show you if the toolchain is finding incompatible versions.

Answer (score 27):

I have the exact same problem, running this command solves it:

`go get -u -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3`

Another tip: http://kokizzu.blogspot.co.id/2016/06/solution-for-golang-slow-compile.html

Comment: How does this solve it exactly? What does it do to speed things up?

Comment: I have the same problem, and it turns out that each I I built, go-sqlite3 is rebuilt again. And this indeed solved my problem.

Comment: For some reason it did the same to me... Weird

Comment: JimB's answer explains what is happening here. The sqlite3 package must have been upgraded so Go will then fetch it from Github and rebuild it. If you do the `go get -u` command manually, it will upgrade the local copy properly so that it doesn't need to rebuild.

Answer (score 19):

Using go1.6,

Simply run `go build -i`.

It will compile all the dependencies and store them at `$GOPATH/pkg/*/*` as **.a** files.

Later when you run `go run main.go`, everything is much faster.

What s really great is that if you use vendored dependencies (IE: a vendor folder in your project), deps are built appropriately within `$GOPATH/pkg/**/yourproject/vendor/**`

So you don t have to `go get install/get/whatever` and have a mix of vendor / global dependencies.

I suspect you got to re-build **.a** files after deps update (glide update or smthg like this), but i did not test that yet.

Comment: If your project is in a package, for example `api`, you’d run `go build -i api`

Comment: FYI the `-i` flag no longer has any benefit as of Go 1.10. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41696

Answer (score 6):

After Go 1.10, you'd just need to type `go build`. You'd not need to type: `go build -i`.

> *From the draft Go 1.10 document, [here](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10)*.
>
> ---
>
> **Build & Install**
>
> The go build command now detects out-of-date packages purely based on the content of source files, specified build flags, and metadata stored in the compiled packages. Modification times are no longer consulted or relevant. **The old advice to add -a to force a rebuild in cases where the modification times were misleading for one reason or another (for example, changes in build flags) is no longer necessary**: builds now always detect when packages must be rebuilt. (If you observe otherwise, please file a bug.)
>
> ...
>
> **The go build command now maintains a cache of recently built packages, separate from the installed packages in $GOROOT/pkg or $GOPATH/pkg.** The effect of the cache should be to speed builds that do not explicitly install packages or when switching between different copies of source code (for example, when changing back and forth between different branches in a version control system). **The old advice to add the -i flag for speed, as in go build -i or go test -i, is no longer necessary: builds run just as fast without -i. For more details, see go help cache.**

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced the same problem - updating from 1.4 to 1.5. It seems that the olds versions are somehow incompatible or are being rebuild every time as `go build -x` shows. Executing `go get -v` invalidates all packages or refetches them, I am not quite sure and `go build -x` shows quite less output.

Comment: I think this may be best as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can build sqlite3 like this:

```
cd ./vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/
go install
```

After that your project will b built much faster.