# How to improve Golang compilation speed?

Tags: performance, sqlite, compilation, go

I'm trying to find a way to make the compilation of a Go program faster. It is currently about 30 seconds, which makes it slow to work with the project.

When I run `go build -v`, I see that most of the time is spent compiling [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) (which links to the C sqlite lib). However, since this lib never changes, I'm wondering if it's possible to prevent the build tool from recompiling this every time?

Comment: Potential duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341654/go-build-became-very-slow-after-installing-a-new-version-of-go

Comment: The compilation speed will improve with Go 1.10 (Q1 2018): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47109826/6309

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try `go install -a github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` which will install the compiled-against-Go-1.3 package into your $GOPATH.

Right now, you likely have an older version installed under `$GOPATH/pkg/` and therefore Go is recompiling it for every build.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to you upgrading to go 1.3

I had to remove $GOPATH/pkg to get rid of old (incompatible) binaries
and then it was able to cache compilation results again

Answer (score 0):

In Go 1.10 no need to run `go install` etc. Just use `go build`. The new version uses a build cache to determine which packages need to be re-compiled.

Check out: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned in the comments above, and in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47109826/6309

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that one.